# Body content formatting on mobile

Tags: feature-request, markdown, mobile-web, editor

I recently joined SO and related sites, and whilst raising a question I noticed that there was no *obvious* way for me to apply Markdown styling to body content via mobile.

For instance, if I were to post a section of code, I would have to rely on another user to edit my post to correct the formatting, or I would have to go to a desktop browser to do so.
I also noticed that when tapping into the body section, mobile browsers zoom in (likely due to font-size) which makes the editing/creation experience a little jarring/unfriendly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @a-stone-arachnid. A prime example where, if I were on a desktop browser, I could’ve paragraphed that myself. However for some reason if I hit “return” on my keyboard (mobile, iOS (iPhone XS Max), Chrome & Safari), the content (this reply as another example) gets published, as opposed to adding a new line. It can be a fairly jarring experience for a newbie such as myself!

Comment: Just FYI, comments always get published when you press `return`, but questions/answers don't.

Comment: Ahhhhh, OK - I might be getting confused (it’s late)! Thanks for confirming that for me though. I thought I was going crazy!

Comment: You can't put newlines in comments, which is why this behavior is by design. It works the same way on the full site. Hitting return causes a comment to be submitted. You're also given an edit window just in case this causes confusion. :)

Comment: If you want, you could click the "Full site" link in the footer. This will switch out the mobile theme with the theme that is used in desktop mode. The site is responsive so it will re-size to fit mobile devices. Unfortunately, the powers-that-be are unlikely to make any more changes to the mobile theme. They will probably focus on making the desktop theme more mobile friendly before removing the mobile theme completely.

Comment: Also, if you want to go back to the mobile theme, just click the "Mobile" link in the footer.

Comment: Mobile theme will go away at some point, when responsive design is complete.

Comment: Thanks guys - so far I have been a "purely mobile" contributor/requestor so wasn't aware that this was standard desktop functionality as well! Apologies! The responsive design would definitely go a long way to aide new users (such as myself) or those that are not familiar with "manual" Markdown formatting (we do live in a world of WYSIWYG after-all). I don't suppose there's anywhere to keep track of responsive design development?